# Exposing last 100 nodes for a mobile app in Drupal 9.5

Tags: drupal-9

last_100_nodes:

for Drupal 9.5 to expose the last 100 nodes in JSON format, fetching only the nid, created, title, body (filtered), and field_image (discovering and displaying the complete URL to the image field).

I am trying to create a fluter application where I need these data from my Drupal 9.
I need help to finalise this: https://github.com/babulgogoi/last_100_nodes

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\last_100_nodes\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\jsonapi\ResourceType\ResourceTypeRepository;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Class Last100NodesController.
 */
class Last100NodesController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * The JSON:API resource type repository.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\jsonapi\ResourceType\ResourceTypeRepository
   */
  protected $resourceTypeRepository;

  /**
   * Last100NodesController constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\jsonapi\ResourceType\ResourceTypeRepository $resource_type_repository
   *   The JSON:API resource type repository.
   */
  public function __construct(ResourceTypeRepository $resource_type_repository) {
    $this->resourceTypeRepository = $resource_type_repository;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('jsonapi.resource_type.repository')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Gets the last 100 nodes in DESC order nid in JSON format.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
   *   The JSON response.
   */
 public function getLast100Nodes() {
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
  $query->sort('created', 'DESC');
  $query->range(0, 100);
  $nodes = $query->execute();

  $nodes_array = [];
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node_array = [
      'nid' => $node->id(),
      'created' => $node->getCreatedTime(),
      'title' => $node->getTitle(),
      'body' => $node->getBody()->getValue(),
      'filtered_body' => filter_xss($node->getBody()->getValue()),
    ];

    // Get the image field URL.
    $image_field = $node->field_image->getValue();
    if (!empty($image_field)) {
      $image_uri = $image_field[0]['uri'];
      $image_url = $this->resourceTypeRepository->get('file')
        ->getNormalizationReference(file_load($image_uri));
      $node_array['field_image'] = $image_url;
    }

    $nodes_array[] = $node_array;
  }

  $response = new JsonResponse($nodes_array);
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return $response;
}
```

Thank you!